# Convert timestramp to datetime wrong AM/PM

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

When i convert datetime to timestamp with am/pm and return timestamp back to datetime  again it alway return 'am' even the actually datetime that i input is have 'pm'

This is my code.

```
from datetime import date, datetime

# convert datetime to timestamp
dt_tsp = datetime.timestamp(datetime.strptime('09 June 2020 02:47 PM', '%d %B %Y %H:%M %p'))

# convert timestramp to datetime
tsp_dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(dt_tsp).strftime('%d %B %Y %H:%M %p')

# result
print(tsp_dt)
# 09 June 2020 02:47 AM // alway am
```

So how can i fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your format string, `%p` needs to be used with `%I` for parsing hours (see the third note in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)):

> 3. When used with the strptime() method, the %p directive only affects the output hour field if the %I directive is used to parse the
>      hour.

So change your code to use `%I` instead of `%H`:

```
from datetime import date, datetime

dt_tsp = datetime.timestamp(datetime.strptime('09 June 2020 02:47 PM', '%d %B %Y %I:%M %p'))
tsp_dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(dt_tsp).strftime('%d %B %Y %I:%M %p')
print(tsp_dt)
```

Output:

```
09 June 2020 02:47 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

`%H` means 24-hour clock. To use 12-hour clock, replace `%H` with `%I`. And in the future please **read the documentation**…

Comment: Thank you very much, it very my mistake.